# Converting C Macros to Actionscript 3

Tags: c, actionscript-3, actionscript, macros

I am trying to convert a macro in C to something that would work similarly in Actionscript.

The C macro takes a string, and using `##` checks the type against other macros to check that the item's property is of the right type.

To clarify, the C:

```
...
#define STACK_NUM     52
...
#define CHECK_TYPE(i, t)      \
( ((i).type == t##_NUM) )     \
```

I'm trying to convert this into something of the same in Actionscript. The current way I am doing it is creating a class

```
public class StringMacro extends String {
    public var macro:int;

    public function
    StringMacro(value:int)
    {
        super();
        macro = value;
    }
}
```

and defining all the macros from C in variables of this class, but this takes up a large amount of space and I really don't want to do it this way.

So, what I came up with was something like this:

```
public class Macros {
    ...
    public var STACK_NUM:uint = 52;
    ...

    public function
    Macros()
    {
    }

}
```

I want to reference the Macros class doing something like this:

```
private var macros:Macros = new Macros();
if(CHECK_TYPE(10, STACK))    
    ....

private function
CHECK_TYPE(value:int, t:String):Boolean
{
    if(value == macros.(t)) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

so I can pass t into the function and it will check it among the definitions in the Macro class.

Is there a way to make this work or something like it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can access values that way, you need to use slightly different syntax though.

DO:

```
macros[t]
```

NOT:

```
macros.(t)
```

You may also want to consider using static vars for this, so you don't have to create an instance of the Macros class. If that fits in with your design.

Comment: Thanks Tyler, the static var idea was the exact thing I needed.